# Emacs attempts to open ESS data directory while working

Tags: r, emacs, ess, datadirectory

I am cording on R (version 3.1.1) in emacs (version 24.3.1) using the ESS[S] (version 13.09) mode. Occasionally, while I am working the minibuffer pops up with the following

```
ESS (*R:2*, R (newest)) starting data directory? c:/Users/vince151/Documents/Dissertation/
```

I am uncertain as to why this keeps appearing. If I hit enter it opens a new buffer of R usually called R:2 and runs the following code.

```
options(chmhelp=FALSE, help_type="text")
options(STERM='iESS', str.dendrogram.last="'", editor='emacsclient.exe', show.error.locations=TRUE)
```

It often seem that the minibuffer opens when autocomplete is active. Is there a known bug when using these two that I was unable to find by searching?

I also noticed that is occasionally opens a blank buffer called ess-command-output.

This problem continues to happen even after an additional r buffer is open and I can easily open 5 buffers of R, if I don't pay enough attention, at which point emacs typically freezes.

Comment: I have been wondering about this for some time as well.  I get the same problem every now and again, also during an autocompletion.  My 'fix' has been to immediately save and reboot emacs.  I hope this gets resolved.

Answer (score 1):

taken from the manual: http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#Customizing-startup

If you do not wish ESS to prompt for a starting directory when starting a new process, set the variable **ess-ask-for-ess-directory** to **nil**.

```
(setq ess-ask-for-ess-directory nil)
```

It'll solve your problem.

Cheers,

LEslie